# Find all homomorphic images of Klein Four Group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here is my solution but it is incomplete Plz Help what to do.

$K_4=\{e, a, b, ab\}$. Let $N$ be a normal subgroups of $K_4$. By Lagrange's theorem the only possibilities for $|N|$ are 1,2 and 4. We know that every normal subgroup of a group of a group $G$ is the kernel of homomorphism of $G$. So the homomorphic images of $K_4$ are the as the factor group $K_4/N$ of $K_4$. When $|N|=1$, we have $K_4/N\simeq K_4$. When $|N|=2$, we have $K_4/\{e, a\}=\{e, a, b, ab\}$, $K_4/\{e, b\}=\{e, a, b, ab\}$. So in both cases $K_4/N\simeq K_4$ but in case $K_4/\{e, c\}=\{e, c, a, ac,b,bc,ab,abc\}$., I don't know what is this set isomorphic to be? Plz help me.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Hint: $K_4/\{e,a\}$ will have two elements, not the four you wrote. Each will be a coset. Also: please use mathjax to write mathematics: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for this.But how we get k4/{e, a}=2 elements

Comment: I have edited your post. Please check whether it is fine or not. Anyway, it seems to me that you have misunderstood the quotient group. It will be very useful to understand it first.

Comment: If your question has been mostly answered, it would be nice to accept the answer so that the answerer gets credit for his or her work. If you think you did not get a complete answer, that can happen for a few reasons. $1$) We don't know how much you know, so we don't know what we can take for granted. It is impossible to always go back to the beginning. $2$) If someone is learning, we think it is usually best that they figure out part of the problem. If they can't they probably need to go back and relearn some of the concepts. $3$ The topic may have been well covered elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

Up to isomorphism there are only 3 homomorphic images $K_4$, $Z_2$, and the trivial group with only $1$ element.
You are on the right track considering normal subgroups. (In this case all subgroups are normal.) But your calculation of quotient groups is incorrect. Note that $|G/N|$ = $|G|/|N|$.

The set I think you want, the set underlying the quotient group $K_4/\{e, a\}$, is a set with two elements. Each of those two elements are themselves sets with two elements. The set you want is $\{\{e,a\},\{b.ab\}\}$. The group multiplication is what it must be for a two element group to be a group with $\{e,a\}$ the identity element.

Comment: Plz Tell Me how to find these sets Am I Ryt In Finding in quotient sets

Comment: Can you plz find the one set k4/{e, a}=? I shall be highly grateful to you for this

Comment: This is elementary group theory. it should be in any text or see a very good description here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/902547/465208